# bootstrap carousel in angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use bootstrap carousel in angular template
i have a data array contains my images that i want to show them in slider 
 each object in the array is

```
{"path": "the path of the image" ,"id":"the id of the image","class":"active 
 or empty value"}
```

now my angular code is :

```
<div *ngFor="let mySlideImage of mySlideImages">
                    <div class="item" [className]="'mySlideImage.class'">
                      <img src="{{mySlideImage.path}}" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

what is happening that all pics are sowing at the same vertically 
although i tried with static values and it worked fine
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that this is the true way!

```
<div class="item slider-item"[ngClass]="{
                    'active': mySlideImage.class == 'active'

                  }" *ngFor="let mySlideImage of mySlideImages">
                    <img src="{{mySlideImage.path}}" alt="...">
                </div>
```